# Simple post to Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I'm trying to get a post request to work with the web api. Following is my api controller.

```
public class WebsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void PostOne(string id)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void PostTwo(Temp id)
    {
    }
}
```

I have altered the webapi route to take the action into account. the Temp model look something like this.

```
public class Temp
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

my view look something like this

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
{
    Url = "/api/webs/postone",
    HttpMethod = "post"
}))
{
    <input name="id" id="id" value="2" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

the above code does not work at all with the postone unless I put the [FromBody] attribute in front of the parameter like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostOne([FromBody]string id)
{
}
```

then it hits the action, but the id is still null. It doesn't get populated with the value in the textbox.

But, if I change the `Url` of the `Ajax.BeginForm` to `posttwo` which take the model `Temp`, it works nicely and the `Id` field gets the proper value in the textbox.

can anyone please explain me the reason for this to happen and how I can post a simple value to a web api action? I mean, why can it bind a complex type but not a simple type.

Comment: yeah, i know. It just wasted a half of my work day just to find out that little clue of not giving a name to the parameter in jQuery ajax.

Comment: Hmm... where are all the comments?

Comment: That's a bit strange... might have to report and see what went wrong. Is it possible that the users got deleted and indirectly deleted the comments?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It's been quite sometime since I asked this question. Now I understand it more clearly, I'm going to put a more complete answer to help others.

In Web API, it's very simple to remember how parameter binding is happening.

- if you `POST` simple types, Web API tries to bind it from the URL
- if you `POST` complex type, Web API tries to bind it from the body of
  the request (this uses a `media-type` formatter).
- If you want to bind a complex type from the URL, you'll use `[FromUri]` in your action parameter. The limitation of this is down to how long your data going to be and if it exceeds the url character limit.

  `public IHttpActionResult Put([FromUri] ViewModel data) { ... }`
- If you want to bind a simple type from the request body, you'll use [FromBody] in your action parameter.

  `public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody] string name) { ... }`

as a side note, say you are making a `PUT` request (just a string) to update something. If you decide not to append it to the URL and pass as a complex type with just one property in the model, then the `data` parameter in jQuery ajax will look something like below. The object you pass to data parameter has only one property with empty property name.

```
var myName = 'ABC';
$.ajax({url:.., data: {'': myName}});
```

and your web api action will look something like below.

```
public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody] string name){ ... }
```

This asp.net page explains it all. 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Caution: Will not work!    
'public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }'
The reason for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a non-buffered stream that can only be read once.