# JQuery / MVC / ajax how to post data to controller using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am tring to pass data using ajax and trigger conteroller in my mvc project

this is my controller

```
public class FileController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string data)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

this is the js

```
 $('#getmessage').on('click', function () {
        var text = '';
        $('#discussion>li').each(function () {
            text += $(this).text();
            text += '\n'
        })
        console.log(text)

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:22828/File/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            data: text,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("data sended");
            }
        })
    })
```

I need to pass the text to the controller, but in my controller I get `NULL`
Can someone please put some light on this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Change your Javascript to this:

```
$('#getmessage').on('click', function () {
        var text = '';
        $('#discussion>li').each(function () {
            text += $(this).text();
            text += '\n'
        })
        console.log(text)

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:22828/File/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { data: text }, // This is all you have to change
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("data sended");
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: controller still gets data = null

Comment: When you do `console.log(text)`, is there anything? Also please remember to close your lines with `;` so it makes it easier for everyone to know where a line starts and stops.

Comment: Ok, open your /App_Start/RouteConfig.cs and paste here in the comment the contents of the method `public static void RegisterRoutes( RouteCollection routes )` please...

Comment: it's working now, I changed my type to 'GET' insted of post but now I have to send it in the url but its ok for now.

Comment: Ok great...You can also just change `type: 'GET'`

Comment: But i think Just changing type to `GET` is not a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the record `data` like this,

```
url: 'File/Index?data=' + text, // Just make change here..
```

You just need to change the `URL` that you are passing to the controller `Action` like this.

```
$('#getmessage').on('click', function () {
    var text = '';
    $('#discussion>li').each(function () {
        text += $(this).text();
        text += '\n'
    })
    console.log(text)

    $.ajax({
        url: 'File/Index?data=' + text, // Just make change here..
        type: 'POST',
        data: text,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("data send");
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: still not working, getting text = null in my conteroller

Comment: Check your text in JavaScript first by putting 'debugger' into it. And also check by put static value...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `[FromBody]` tag in your controller. By default, ASP.NET will try to bind simple parameters from the URL, and only complex ones from the body.

Try it like this:

```
public class FileController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index([FromBody] string data)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

For more details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33667496/886044) related answer.