# Why I get error when post method in web api controller is called?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have this angularjs service:

```
function checkCredentials(username,password) {
    return $http.post(config.baseUrl + "api/login/", username, password)
}
```

And this web api:

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    private MorenoContext _context;

    public LoginController()
    {
        _context = new MorenoContext();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string username, string password)
    {
        return Ok("test");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

But when try to call web api method with help of checkCredentials() client function I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/myProjectName/api/login/
```

Any idea why I get the error?

Comment: With web api post your parameters as an object OR individual parameters using query string. `return $http.post(config.baseUrl + "api/login/?username="+username+"&password="+ password)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple post to Web Api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093603/simple-post-to-web-api)