# Why I got an 404 error when I try to post data to a WebAPI action?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

Why I got an 404 error when I try to post data to a WebAPI action?

C#:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public List<Product> GetProductsByCategoryId(int categoryId, string title)
    {
        return new List<Product>
        {
            new Product { Id = 1 , Name = "Test" }
        };
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/products',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        categoryId: 12,
        title: 'ABC'
    },
})
```

[image]

Comment: url: '/api/products' ? what is product?

Comment: you're not calling to the method, if your path is `/api/products` you have still to call the method name: `/api/products/GetProductsByCategoryId`

Comment: @Satpal, I add the correct image.

Comment: @kosmos my route config is `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );`

Comment: but you're still getting a 404... try commeting the route map line and call directly the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33667496/4107888).

> It's been quite sometime since I asked this question. Now I understand
>   it more clearly, I'm going to put a more complete answer to help
>   others.
>
> In Web API, it's very simple to remember how parameter binding is
>   happening.
>
> - if you `POST` simple types, Web API tries to bind it from the URL
> - if you `POST` complex type, Web API tries to bind it from the body of    the request (this uses a `media-type` formatter).
> - If you want to bind a complex type from the URL, you'll use `[FromUri]` in your action parameter. The limitation of this is down
>     to how long your data going to be and if it exceeds the url character
>     limit.
>
>   `public IHttpActionResult Put([FromUri] ViewModel data) { ... }`
> - If you want to bind a simple type from the request body, you'll use [FromBody] in your action parameter.
>
>   `public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody] string name) { ... }`
>
> as a side note, say you are making a `PUT` request (just a string) to
>   update something. If you decide not to append it to the URL and pass
>   as a complex type with just one property in the model, then the `data`
>   parameter in jQuery ajax will look something like below. The object
>   you pass to data parameter has only one property with empty property
>   name.
>
> ```
> var myName = 'ABC';
> $.ajax({url:.., data: {'': myName}});
> ```
>
> and your web api action will look something like below.
>
> ```
> public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody] string name){ ... }
> ```
>
> This asp.net page explains it all. 
>   http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api
>
> tnx @Amila

Answer (score 0):

By default, Web API tries to [match](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) simple parameters from the URI, but you are supplying them in the body. In my original answer, I forgot you can't use `FromBodyAttribute` more than once. In this case, I'd create a model class to contain the values. Web API will then read this "complex" type from the body.

```
public class ProductCategoryModel
{
   public int CategoryId { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public List<Product> GetProductsByCategoryId(ProductCategoryModel model)
    {
        return new List<Product>
        {
            new Product { Id = 1 , Name = "Test" }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't put two `[FromBody]` attribute. Error: `Can't bind multiple parameters ('categoryId' and 'title') to the request's content.`

Comment: This is correct. My mistake in my deleted answer was not making it clear this should be a model as opposed to a parameter.