# How to pass string array as parameter to the webservice in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string getUser(string[] username){
    string[] result= new string[5];
    string qry="";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        username[i]= a;
        qry="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USERNAME='" + a + "' ";
        result[i] = getjsondata(qry);
        return result[i];  
    }

}
```

When I try to execute a method, it shows the test form is only available for methods with primitive types as parameters. I tried out `List` as parameter, that also fails. I want to pass `string[]` as parameter to the `WebMethod`.

Comment: The code as shown is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and it won't work if a name contains an apostrophe. The code needs to be modified to use SQL parameters instead of string concatenation, which will solve both those issues.

Comment: Completely unrelated but I would consider using Web API, much more fluent, self documenting and a joy to work with. Took me a day to pick up the fundamentals and build a working solution. Also Entity Framework? If your bound by framework/work constraints. Please ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `GET` operation, which only supports URL / querystring parameters.

For non-primitive parameter types you need to use the HTTP body. In order to use the body you should use a `POST` or one of the other HTTP operations.

See this answer for more details: [Simple post to Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093603/simple-post-to-web-api)