# AJAX paramter to ASP .NET Core 2 Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core-2.0

I'd like to pass an AJAX parameter to the MVC Controller in ASP .Net Core 2.

This is what i tried :

```
function getMatchesFromChampionshipAsync(championship) {
    console.log(championship);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Bets/Matches",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "championship": championship },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response)
        }
    })
}
```

I'm sure that the parameter `championship` is correct (I also tried to log it), but the Controller always receives `null`.
 This is the Controller Action Method code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Matches([FromBody] string championship) {
        return Json(championship);
    }
```

The browser also alerts `null`.
I also read other questions about it but no one worked.

Comment: read about model binding in .net core 2

Comment: it will work if you just pass the object as data without wrapping it in another object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple post to Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093603/simple-post-to-web-api)

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama i've tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved using a Class with a single property called `Championship` :

```
public  class Value {
        public String Championship { get; set; }
}
```

and using it as Model in the Action method :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Matches([FromBody] Value ch) {
    return Json(ch.Championship);
}
```

I don't know if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

Lately, I have really liked using a formData object in javascript to pass data from xhr/ajax to post to MVC actions. Here is an example:

```
    var nameFormDataHere = new FormData();
    nameFormDataHere.append("championship", championship);
    $.ajax({
    url: "/Bets/Matches",
    type: "POST",
    data: nameFormDataHere,
    dataType: "json"
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Just like your example above you will need to create a model(a class) with a property and have the data annotation [HttpPost] above the action that ajax is posting to, with the new model(class) as a parameter into the action. This is from your example above:

Model:

```
    public  class Value{
        public String Championship { get; set; }
    }
```

Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Matches(Value ch) {
        return Json(ch.Championship);
    }
```

I have used this several times and have never had to use the [FromBody] annotation for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "contentType" qualifier in your ajax statement or simply wrap your parameter in JSON.stringify ie. data:JSON.stringify(championship).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding **traditional: true**

```
function getMatchesFromChampionshipAsync(championship) {
console.log(championship);
$.ajax({
    url: "/Bets/Matches",
    type: "POST",
    data: { "championship": championship },
    traditional: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response)
    }
})}
```

Comment: still null, in the output I get :
`Chance3>       Executing action method Chance3.Controllers.BetsController.Matches (Chance3) with arguments () - ModelState is Invalid`

Comment: Can you comment out the contentType and dataType lines and try?

Comment: I can comment only dataType, but nothing changed

Comment: If you want to keep the content type as application/json , try changing your data to -  data: JSON.stringify({ "championship": championship })