# C# Web Api call is not invoking from jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, data-binding

I am making a `POST` `web-api` call from a jQuery script, but the data is not binding. `Page` is `null`

**Jquery**

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    myTimer= setInterval( "StartTimer()", 1000);
});
function StartTimer()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        url: "/api/sitehit/LogHit/",  //method Name 
        data:  'Page=test' ,
        dataType: 'text/plain',
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.responsetext);
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("error logging hit");
    }).success(function () {
        alert("success logging hit");
    });
    clearInterval(myTimer);
}
```

**C# code**

```
public class SiteHitController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void LogHit(string Page)  // Page not binding
    {
        var c= Page; // Page is null
    }
}
```

Comment: Not helpful. I am invoking `API/Controller/Action/StringData` but still no result

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093603/simple-post-to-web-api..

Comment: Also make sure that your routing setup is correct, since there is not route attribute specified for methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no route set for `/api/sitehit/LogHit` in the controller.  ApiControllers don't work the same way as regular MVC controllers.  The name of the action is not the route of the endpoint, unless you specify it.

You could add route attribute  to the controller action.

```
[Route("LogHit")]
[HttpPost]
public void LogHit(string Page)
{
}
```

Or (assuming there are no other HttpPost methods on the controller) change the `jQuery` url to `url: '/api/sitehit'`.

There are multiple ways to bind the data, depending on which content type you want to send.  Assuming you want to use JSON you can do something like the following.

Create a model to bind to and add `[FromBody]` to the controller action parameter:

```
public class MyModelDto
{
    public string Page { get; set; }
}

[Route("LogHit")]
[HttpPost]
public void LogHit([FromBody] MyModelDto model) // add FromBody here
{
    // model.Page will contain "test"
}
```

Then make sure you're sending JSON in the ajax call by using `JSON.stringify()` to stringify the data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "/api/sitehit/LogHit",
    data: JSON.stringify({Page: 'test'}),  // use JSON.stringify()
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // can use response data here
        alert("success logging hit");
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.responsetext);
    }
});
```

This should correctly bind to your controller now.

If you're sending form data `x-www-form-urlencoded` then use `[FromForm]` instead and you don't need to use `JSON.stringify()`, but in this case the parameters should be sent in query string form: `page=test&prop2=test2`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to bind, please share complete information not partial. I am now using ` contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            url: "/api/sitehit/LogHit/" ` and now its hitting but data is not binding

Comment: @Sujoy updated answer.  There are multiple ways to bind, depending on content type. Use `[FromBody]` for JSON or `[FromForm]` if it's form data.

Comment: Why do you make things complicated. I just want to bind it as string, because my controller-action accepts string. Moreover, it is not an issue of route because my code works well with integer parameter.

Comment: Of course everyone knows it's possible, but the question is 'how'. Your answer is not adequate. I modified the question, you may try once again.

Comment: Thanks, I did not ask for different ways. I was looking for the simplest way, probably 
 with string. I found a simple way myself.

Answer (score 0):

**Following code worked:**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/api/sitehit/LogHit?Page=" + window.location.href,   
        //dataType: 'json',
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.responsetext);
        }
    });
```